# pandas apply typeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable, applying custom function over a particular column in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, typeerror, apply

I'm using a lambda function to create a new data frame column based on a custom function, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I've posted the code and error below, and it looks like the issue isn't with the lambda function, but the original custom function (get_bins).

The values in df['X'] are float values, but the get_bin function works when it's applied outside the lambda function. Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
def get_bins(df):
    interval_range = pd.interval_range(start = min(df), end = max(df) + 5, freq=5, closed = 'left')
    bins = pd.cut(df,interval_range)
    return (bins)


df_ex['bins'] = df_ex.apply(lambda i: get_bins(i['X']), axis = 1)
```

```
 
---> 10 df['bins'] = df.apply(lambda i: get_bins(i['X']), axis = 1)

<ipython-input-7-7bbf11fd23d3> in get_bins(d)
      2 
      3 def get_bins(d):
----> 4     interval_range = pd.intervalpandas apply typeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable_range(start = min(d), end = max(d) + 5, freq=5, closed = 'left')
      5     bins = pd.cut(d,interval_range)
      6     return (bins)

TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using df.apply(..., axis=1), you are applying your custom function to the whole row. This row is then converted to a serie (the transposed matrix of your initial row if you will).

When you are using "lambda i: get_bins(i['X'])", then you are passing the only row['X'] value to your get_bins function. row['X'] beeing a float, python can't evaluate a min or max.

Nota : if you want to understand better, you can do :

```
def my_print(x):
  print(x)
  print('-'*50)
df.apply(my_print, axis=1)
```

Comment: I've seen other responses on stack where when applying a custom function over one column, lambda i: get_bins(i['X']), that is the code they use. I'm also not sure why python can't evaluate a min or a max over a float.....doesn't a float just mean it's a non integer value?

Comment: To apply it to a column you would rather have to do df_ex['X'].apply(get_bins). Python doesn't allow you to use min(x) whether x is an int or a float. It allows you to find a min/max on an "iterable" (for example a list). Hence the exception message you triggered

Comment: Got it. The get_bin function works however outside of the lambda function. (bins = get_bins(df['X']) works the way I want it to) So I guess I still don't understand why it's not working within the lambda function?

Comment: Did you try the "my_print" function ? It would help you understand what you are passing as a variable to the lambda function.

Comment: I did, and it looks like I'm passing through a dtype object through the function. But I'm still not sure how to correct the error.

Comment: You will find more examples in [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). In short, when you do df.apply(blah, axis=1), you are sucessively passing all the rows as arguments to blah ; when you do df['X'].apply(blah), you are passing the whole 'X' column as an argument. When you combine 'axis=1' and i['X'] in your lambda, you are in fact iterating over the values of the 'X' column (looping over the column, which is inefficient), passing all individual values as successive arguments. (And there is no min/max value of just one float value.)